# Make text input into Presentation (external display)

Tags: java, android

I have made external display through Android Presentation class and create an `EditText` on it.
The question is how to make the input from `MainActivity` to `EditText` which on the external display.

```
  public class MainPresentationFragment extends PresentationFragment {

private EditText editText;
public static MainPresentationFragment newInstance(Context context, Display display) {
    MainPresentationFragment mainPresentationFragment = new MainPresentationFragment();
    mainPresentationFragment.setDisplay(context, display);
    return mainPresentationFragment;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_presentation, container, false);
    editText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_editText);
    return rootView;
}

public EditText getEditText() {
    return editText;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made one solution by myself, I set `onKeyDown` listener, through `edittext.append()` help me make input into `edittext` which on the external display. I listen to each Key case by case. I knew this is not a very good solution but it is works for me. Hope got a better idea in the future. I think about why `edittext.requestfocus()` cannot work in `PresentationFragment` and how to make it work right now. Does anyone have a better idea?